# Can AsyncTaskLoader replace AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I feel like `AsyncTaskLoader` is basically a better `AsyncTask`, although i'm not entirely sure i should replace my `AsyncTask` implementations with `AsyncTaskLoader`.

What confuses me is the `Loader` name kinda suggests it should be used for **loading** data.

What if i'd like to **write** data (into a `File` for example) or do any other background operation (that is not loading)?

Are `Loader`s suitable for any background operation, that i would normally use an `AsyncTask` for?

Comment: What is better about AsyncTaskLoader than AsyncTask?  AsyncTaskLoader does not provide for progress updates like AsyncTask does, but otherwse you could use AsyncTaskLoader instead of AsyncTask and just return a null object. What is the point, though?

Comment: @Egg Handling configuration changes is a pain in the ass with `AsyncTask`, but `AsyncTaskLoader` makes it kinda easy, that's the main reason i'm considering it.

Comment: Consider using `IntentService` for long running background tasks, which are not bound to the UI.

Comment: @Egor Yeah, that's the problem, my background operations are relatively short and bound to the UI, but implementing AsyncTask to work properly with configuration changes is just painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loaders are intended for loading data, yes.  The hole that they fill is that you can "re-connect" to it on configuration change when you call `LoaderManager#init()`.  What this will do is,

1. If the Loader has not started, it will start the Loader.
2. If the Loader has started but not finished, it will connect the callback to the Loader and give the callback the data when it's loaded.
3. If the Loader has started and finished, it will *not* start the Loader and pass the information loaded to the callback.

So that means if the user had the phone in a pocket and it just kept rotating over and over again, you wouldn't start a hundred Loading tasks to get one single piece of data.

You wouldn't really care for single, outbound tasks that are fire-and-forget. You may also not want this to happen as you'll probably want all file-writes to execute which would not be the case with Loaders unless you restarted them every time.  In which case, you're defeating the purpose of Loaders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main reason i'm considering Loaders is the handling of configuration changes. It seems really hard to implement it right with AsyncTask. WeakReference could help IF i wouldn't want to call back to the Activity. Using headless Fragments seems like the only way, but they feel like an overkill.

Comment: @justanoob: Another thing you have to watch out for is Loaders will cancel the previous Load if you restart it.  AsyncTask will not do it. IntentService with LocalBroadcastReceiver may be an easier way to uncouple the UI from the background task.  All tasks you post will eventually execute, and your Activity only has to listen to the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: My problem with the IntentService + LocalBroadcastReceiver approach is also with configuration changes. Even if i register/unregister my receiver in onCreate()/onDestroy(), it is possible that the broadcast comes during an orientation change, after onDestroy() and before onCreate(), in which case i don't receive the broadcast (i've tested it).

Comment: @justanoob You only need to do it that way if it's an important operation that must be complete.  Activities are volatile so the user could leave the Activity and Android could pull its process from memory all before your operation completes.  If that happens, then you may have bigger issues missing a broadcast. At the same time, if that's OK then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @justanoob sticky broadcasts could help with the issue of missing them